# Using R and flowCore's write.FCS to append a parameter

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a script that will open an FCS file, create a parameter from the sum of the other parameters, and write that back out as a legal FCS.

My code looks like this:

```
require("flowCore")

fname = paste(getwd(),"/8b_tonsil2_1.fcs", sep="");
outname = paste(getwd(),"/8bOUT.fcs", sep="");
fcs <- read.FCS(fname,transformation = FALSE)

nCols1 <- ncol(fcs)
sum <-rowSums(fcs@exprs[,2:nCols1])
fcs@exprs <- cbind(fcs@exprs, sum)
write.FCS(cytof, outname)
```

This does not work because I am adding to the fcs@exprs matrix but not updating the description and parameters sections to match.

Does anyone have an example of rewriting these sections to match changes in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How about this:

```
library('flowCore')
## Read the original file
original <- read.FCS("/Users/josef/Downloads/myFCS.fcs")

## Let's create a new parameter as an AnnotatedDataFrame by copying the first parameter from the original flowFrame
new_p <- parameters(original)[1,]

## Now, let's change it's name from $P1 to $Px (whatever the next new number is)
new_p_number <- as.integer(dim(original)[2]+1)
rownames(new_p) <- c(paste0("$P", new_p_number))

## Now, let's combine the original parameter with the new parameter 
library('BiocGenerics') ## for the combine function
allPars <- combine(parameters(original), new_p)

## Fix the name and description of the newly added parameter, say we want to be calling it cluster_id
new_p_name <- "cluster_id"
allPars@data$name[new_p_number] <- new_p_name
allPars@data$desc[new_p_number] <- new_p_name

## Check that allPars contains what it should
allPars@data

## Let's get our cluster ID into a single column matrix
## Using random numbers here; replace with your own code as appropriate
num.events <- as.integer(dim(original)[1])
cluster_ids <- as.matrix(runif(num.events, 1, max(original@exprs)), ncol=1)
new_exprs <- cbind(original@exprs, cluster_ids)

## Now, let's get all the original keywords and let's add to it
new_kw <- original@description
new_kw["$PAR"] <- as.character(new_p_number)
new_kw[paste0("$P",as.character(new_p_number),"N")] <- new_p_name
new_kw[paste0("$P",as.character(new_p_number),"S")] <- new_p_name
new_kw[paste0("$P",as.character(new_p_number),"E")] <- "0,0"
new_kw[paste0("$P",as.character(new_p_number),"G")] <- "1"
new_kw[paste0("$P",as.character(new_p_number),"B")] <- new_kw["$P1B"]
new_kw[paste0("$P",as.character(new_p_number),"R")] <- new_kw["$P1R"]
new_kw[paste0("flowCore_$P",as.character(new_p_number),"Rmin")] <- new_kw["flowCore_$P1Rmin"]
new_kw[paste0("flowCore_$P",as.character(new_p_number),"Rmax")] <- new_kw["flowCore_$P1Rmax"]

## Now, let's just combine it into a new flowFrame
new_fcs <- new("flowFrame", exprs=new_exprs, parameters=allPars, description=new_kw)

## Now, let's just use the regular write.FCS from flowCore to save the new FCS file.
write.FCS(new_fcs, filename="/Users/josef/Downloads/flowjo_test/FCSwithParAdded.fcs", delimiter="#")

## This new file should now be readable nicely R or any other software.
```

Best,
Josef

*Josef Spidlen, Ph.D., Director of Bioinformatics, FlowJo*

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does indeed add a parameter to a `flowFrame`. However, the matrix that is saved to the `exprs` slot of the new `flowFrame` lacks a column name for the added parameter. This is inconsistent with the other columns. To fix this, in the accepted answer replace the code block to create the new expression matrix, `new_exprs`, with the following:

```
## Let's get our cluster ID into a single column matrix
## Using random numbers here; replace with your own code as appropriate
orig_col_names <- dimnames(original@exprs)[[2]] 
num.events <- as.integer(dim(original)[1])
cluster_ids <- as.matrix(runif(num.events, 1, max(original@exprs)), ncol=1)
new_exprs <- cbind(original@exprs, cluster_ids)
new_par_col_name <- setNames(new_p_name,
                             paste0("$P",as.character(new_p_number),"N"))
dimnames(new_exprs)[[2]] <- c(orig_col_names, new_par_col_name)
```

(Note that this was proposed as an edit, but was rejected as it apparently should have been an answer/comment; I don't have the rep to comment).